# Will a gas line for my grill be buried?

Tags: natural-gas

I have natural gas coming into the side of my house from an underground pipe.  I am considering (hiring it out to a licensed pro, of course) running a line from the meter on the side to the back of my house, where I have a grill.

Can I have the pipe buried, and if so, at what depth?  I would prefer not to have an above ground line snaking around the house due to aesthetics.  Plus, it might be more susceptible to damage.

Again, not going to attempt this myself, just wondering what my options were.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the contractor will route the line through the basement or crawlspace, and emerge from the back of the house near where the outlet will be.  Snaking around the outside of the house (even underground), is more difficult, and may make the pipe more susceptible to damage. If the piping has to travel any significant distance from the house to the destination, that length of piping will almost certainly be buried. Depending on your location, the piping will be buried anywhere from 18-36".

#### *Notes:*

*If you live in an area prone to freezing. It may be worth asking the installer to install a shutoff where the piping splits off from the main line, and at the end of the run.  This way you can turn the gas on/off at the grill during grilling season, and shut the whole line off when it's not grilling season.*

Comment: Also, in some jurisdictions, a tracer wire must be buried with the external gas pipe to assist finding the pipe during repairs and other construction. The unconnected wire can be energized with a signal to aid identifying its location.